# Image not uploading using nodejs api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I am working with Nodejs and using express js , Right now i am trying to upload image using api but i am getting following error as response

```
Error uploading file.
```

Here is my api.router file

```
router.post('/uploadavatar', apiController.uploadavatar);
```

Here is my "api.controller.js" file

```
var multer  =   require('multer');
 
 var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('userPhoto');
 
 const uploadavatar = function (req, res) {
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
};
```

Comment: The err object will have more details as to why it fails, can you try logging it and update your question?

Comment: return err.message instead to see the exact error